# cloudControl deploys same build several times

Tags: cloudcontrol

I'm running a Spring-Boot application on [cloudControl](https://www.cloudcontrol.com) and a simple Jenkins task to check every 10 minutes whether the application is still available or not. So it occurs every couple days that the check-alive fails, but it is available again only minutes later. The cloudControl log says there was a deployment in these times, but the hash value of the build is the same as no changes were made.

Why are these (IMHO unnecessary) deployments happening?

```
[Wed Sep 10 12:20:16 2014] lb-101 INFO Routing requests to new version
[Wed Sep 10 12:20:44 2014] lb-102 INFO Routing requests to new version
[Wed Sep 10 16:43:50 2014] lxc-1752 INFO Deploying ...
[Wed Sep 10 16:44:03 2014] lxc-1752 INFO Deployed version: b6a4eb94702f9a9aaeb9baa367d7a74c8d1c75e8
[Wed Sep 10 16:44:03 2014] lb-97 INFO Routing requests to new version
[Wed Sep 10 16:44:03 2014] lb-98 INFO Routing requests to new version
...
[Mon Sep 15 08:44:01 2014] lxc-1767 INFO Deploying ...
[Mon Sep 15 08:44:16 2014] lxc-1767 INFO Deployed version: b6a4eb94702f9a9aaeb9baa367d7a74c8d1c75e8
[Mon Sep 15 08:44:16 2014] ngx-72 INFO Routing requests to new version
[Mon Sep 15 08:44:16 2014] lb-120 INFO Routing requests to new version
```

Answer (score 0):

If a deployments is in the free tier its containers are hibernated to free up resources if not used. If hibernated deployments get a request a new container is started to serve that request. This is the behaviour you are seeing.

To avoid having your application hibernated simply scale the deployment up or out.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but actually I'm using a container with 384MB, so it should not hibernate at all...

Comment: Indeed. If that's the case it might be that the host was changed. This happens for various reasons but should never lead to downtime of the application. I suggest you send an email to support@cloudcontrol.de with some more details so we can help you find out what's going on.

Comment: Alright, probably will do so tomorrow. Thanks again!